# Android Spinner set and get tag of selected item

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-spinner, android-adapter

I am creating an android application in which I have to use spinner. I want to set a specific tag with every spinner value. For example spinner have three values low,high and very high want to set three tags 100 , 200 , 300. When user select high. I want the value 200 which is store. I have implemented simple spinner , done this with radio buttons but don't know how to do this task with spinners.Kindly help.

Comment: Just create a data list object of type entityclass which has the property and the name to display, now set this listobject to the spinner, when ever user select the item, onItemSelected of OnItemSelectedListener will be called, get the selected item index and retrieve the item from the list object, you will get what you want, no require to set the switch or other conditions.

Comment: Possibly Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434886/how-android-spinner-displays-radio-button-in-dropdown-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by getting the spinner position you can set value. Spinner position will start from 0.

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0){
                    value = 100;
               }else if(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1){
                  value = 200;
               }else if(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2){
                 value = 300;
               }
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    int i=100;
    spinnerId.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {

        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinnerId:
           if(arg2==0){
              i=100;
        }else if(arg2==1){
              i=200;
        }else{
              i=300;
       }

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```